# How to close fragment if it's not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a new application developer and I add to my app  Bottom Navigation Bar in main activity it's work fine but there are one problem when I try move from Bottom Navigation Bar to fragment of TabLayout, ViewPager my app it becomes fixed and I understand why that happening it's because every time after first time click on botton to view it I create fragment again.

but I don't know how I can solve this problem.but I think if I close it every time when user click another button will solve this problem.

Please if anyone knows solve to this problem help me.

I move from this activity

```
public class NafMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_naf_main);

            BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new MainActivityOderLIstFargmant();//here problem

                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_favorites:
                            selectedFragment = new FragmentHome();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_search:
                            selectedFragment = new FragmentProfile();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_s:
                            selectedFragment = new MainActivity();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                }
            });


        }
    }
```

To this fragment..

```
public class MainActivityOderLIstFargmant extends Fragment {
   TabLayout tabLayout;
   ViewPager viewPager;
   PageAdapterOrderList pageAdapterOrderList;
   TabItem tabChats;
   TabItem tabCalls;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hoome, container, false);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mani_order_list, container, false);

       tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
       tabChats = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabChats);
       tabCalls = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabCalls);
       viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

       pageAdapterOrderList = new PageAdapterOrderList(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
       viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapterOrderList);
       viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


       return rootView;

   }

}
```

And this fragment I view from open MainActivityOderLIstFargmant

```
public class Fragmentlisttwo extends Fragment {


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_o_two, container, false);

            return rootView;

        }
```

I add this example source code to my problem in last button by Name (Search)

https://gofile.io/d/Or9fTf

Comment: Please read about Lifecycles in Android and how to handle UI changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
pageAdapterOrderList = new PageAdapterOrderList(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, to prevent your fragment to recreate, you should use beginTransaction().add() when the first time you click on the bottom navigation menu icon, and with hide(yourCurrentFragment).show(yourFragment) for the next times.
Furthermore, you should keep an instance of each fragment in activity and initial it ONLY when activity is created.
I have a demo code for your case.
Hope it help ^^.

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TransactionFragment mTransactionFragment;
    AnalyticFragment mAnalyticFragment;
    ProfileFragment mProfileFragment;
    StatisticFragment mStatisticFragment;

boolean mTransactionInit = false;
boolean mAnalyticInit = false;
boolean mProfileInit = false;
boolean mStatisticInit = false;

Fragment mVisibleFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallet_container);
    initView();
    setupUI();
    addListener();
}

private void addListener() {
    bnvWalletContainer.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment mFragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_wallet_transaction:
                    if (!mTransactionInit) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fl_container, mTransactionFragment).commit();
                        mTransactionInit = true;
                    } else {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .hide(mVisibleFragment)
                                .show(mTransactionFragment).commit();
                    }
                    mVisibleFragment = mTransactionFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_wallet_1:
                    if (!mAnalyticInit) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fl_container, mAnalyticFragment).commit();
                        mAnalyticInit = true;
                    } else {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .hide(mVisibleFragment)
                                .show(mAnalyticFragment).commit();
                    }
                    mVisibleFragment = mAnalyticFragment;
                    break;
                ....

            return true;
        }
    });
}

void initView() {
    mAnalyticFragment = new AnalyticFragment();
    mTransactionFragment = new TransactionFragment();
    mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    mStatisticFragment = new StatisticFragment();
}

private void setupUI() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fl_container, mTransactionFragment).commit();
    mTransactionInit = true;
    mVisibleFragment = mTransactionFragment;
}
```

}